# Passing $args to a script works differently than passing created array

Tags: powershell, subscript, args

I call a script: "TestArgs1 xxx -T".  From within TestArgs1, I call TestArgs2, trying to pass it the same arguments. If I use: "TestArgs2 @args", switch -T is correctly passed as true.  Also if I copy $args to another array and pass it, it works. But if I create my own array first, (in order to modify some arguments), switch -T is passed as false. Why is this? How can I correctly pass the switch argument? See sample code below:

```
###### TestArgs1
Write-Host "#### pass incoming args ###"
TestArgs2 @args
Write-Host "#### copy incoming args ###"
$a = $args
TestArgs2 @a
Write-Host "#### pass created array ###"
$b = "xxx", "-T"
TestArgs2 @b

###### TestArgs2
function Main {
param ($n, [switch] $t, [switch] $d)
"n = $n"
"t = $t"
}
Main @args

The output of this is the follows:
#### pass incoming args ###
n = xxx
t = True
#### copy incoming args ###
n = xxx
t = True
#### pass created array ###
n = xxx
t = False
```

When I create my own array and pass the same arguments, t shows up as false.

Comment: Your 6th line should be `TestArgs2 @a` instead of `TestArgs2 @args`.

Comment: Yes you are correct. That was a typo. But when I change it, the results are the same. The copied array works but my own array does not.

Comment: The copy will work the same just due to it being a copy. Not sure why that would be in question.

Comment: Yes the copy works the same. My question is why the new array does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell does this because the following two commands behave differently:

```
Some-Command -Param
Some-Command "-Param"
```

In the first case, Some-Command is called with a parameter named Param, in the second case Some-Command is called with a positional argument that has the value "-Param".

With a little digging, we can figure out how PowerShell knows the difference.

```
function foo { $args[0] }
foo -SomeParam | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Force
```

After running the above, we see the following output:

```
TypeName: System.String                                                  

Name                   MemberType   Definition                              
----                   ----------   ----------                              
<CommandParameterName> NoteProperty System.String <CommandParameterName>=SomeParam
```

We see that PowerShell added a NoteProperty to the value in $args.  We can conclude from this that PowerShell is using that NoteProperty when splatting to decide if the value in the array is passed as a value or as a parameter.

So - one solution that I don't recommend - you could add a NoteProperty to your strings that are really parameters.  I don't recommend this because it would rely on an undocumented implementation detail.

An alternative solution is to use a function like my foo function to turn a syntactic switch into a value that splats as a parameter.  That might look like:

```
function Get-AsParameter { $args[0] }
$b = "xxx", (Get-AsParameter -T)
TestArgs @b
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. That solves adding a switch to the $args. Ultimately I really want to do this: (which I should have included in my sample)

    $b = ,"xxx" + $args
    TestArgs2 $b

I want to prepend the first argument to the switches that are passed (TestArgs -T). But this code, as you know, would not work, since $b is a newly created array and remove the note property from the switch.

Comment: The code above was supposed to be:  
`    $b = ,"xxx" + $args; 
    TestArgs2 $b`

Comment: Did you mean: $b = ,"xxx" + $args; TestArgs2 @b?  I might also append instead of prepend.  Either works for your example.  More generally, appending is safer because you won't shift the positional arguments.

Comment: Yes, I should have used the "@". That works. One problem with using the Get-AsParameter function is that I need to use a literal -T. I can't call the function with a variable that contains the switch that I want to add.

Comment: In that case I'd splat a hash table.  You can splat both on one command line:  $b = @{}; $b[$T] = $true; TestArgs2 @args @b

Comment: Very nice. Thanks. You also solved another problem that I was trying to figure out -- how to add a switch parameter to a hash table.

Comment: Is there a way to add un-named positional parameters to the hash table? Or do you have to name them, since otherwise the keys would be null?

Comment: The reason I am asking the last question is because if they are named and they are actually optional positional parameters, an error will be thrown if they are missing.

Comment: I just found the answer to my question at: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I ran your script and got the same for all three:

```
PS C:\> .\TestArgs1.ps1 xxx -T
#### pass incoming args ###
n = xxx
t = False
#### copy incoming args ###
n = xxx
t = False
#### pass created array ###
n = xxx
t = False
```

Code:

```
###### TestArgs2
function TestArgs2 {
param ($n, [switch] $t, [switch] $d)
"n = $n"
"t = $t"
}

###### TestArgs1
Write-Host "#### pass incoming args ###"
TestArgs2 @args
Write-Host "#### copy incoming args ###"
$a = $args
TestArgs2 @a
Write-Host "#### pass created array ###"
$b = "xxx", "-T"
TestArgs2 @b
```

Comment: Main @argsI closed down the PowerShell ISE, recopied my code from here into two new script file and reran it. I get the same result as before: true, true, false.

Comment: I meant to point out in my last post that you left out "Main @args" from TestArgs2. (I couldn't edit my comment).